# WHILE loop issue not working in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query not working fine in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152885/query-not-working-fine-in-while-loop)

I have a WHILE loop where I am trying to insert

```
DECLARE @CurrentOffer int  =121
DECLARE @OldestOffer int  = 115

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Temp WITH (TABLOCK)
        SELECT TOP (100) clubcard  
        FROM TempClub WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE ID BETWEEN @MinClubcardand AND @MaxClubcard

     declare @sql varchar(8000)

     while @OldestOffer <= @CurrentOffer
     begin
          print @CurrentOffer
          print @OldestOffer

          set @sql = 'delete from Temp where Clubcard 
                      in (select Clubcard 
                          from ClubTransaction_' + convert(varchar, @CurrentOffer) +
                     ' with (nolock))'

          print (@sql)
          exec (@sql)

          SET @CurrentOffer = @CurrentOffer-1  

          IF @OldestOffer = @CurrentOffer
          begin
             -- my logic
          end
     end
END
```

What I am doing here is I am inserting the rows by batch into table `Temp` and  checking if exists in table `ClubTransaction_121`

If it does exit I need to delete it here my loop get first 100 clubcard and then checks with `ClubTransaction_121` and moves to check with the next offer that is 120

But my table `Temp` has 3000 rows which need to be checked with table `ClubTransaction_121` with all rows.

It checks only for first 100 records and moves to check with next ClubTransaction_120.

I need to check all my clubcard all 3000 rows with all rows of  `ClubTransaction_121`, `ClubTransaction_120`, `ClubTransaction_119` tables

Comment: Wow, there's some weak database design going on here.

Comment: Yeah, you might consider trying a relational data design.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend getting rid of the TABLOCK and NOLOCK as they can lead to inconsistent data.

Next on each iteration through your loop I would BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION assuming that each step can be considered good if it completes, and that if 10 loops complete, and the 11th fails that it would be ok to not rollback the entire transaction.

something like this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentOffer int  =121
DECLARE @OldestOffer int  = 115

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
     INSERT INTO Temp 
        SELECT TOP (100) clubcard  
        FROM TempClub 
        WHERE ID BETWEEN @MinClubcardand AND @MaxClubcard

     declare @sql varchar(8000)

     while @OldestOffer <= @CurrentOffer
     begin
          print @CurrentOffer
          print @OldestOffer

          set @sql = 'delete from Temp where Clubcard 
                      in (select Clubcard 
                          from ClubTransaction_' + convert(varchar, @CurrentOffer)

          print (@sql)
          exec (@sql)

          SET @CurrentOffer = @CurrentOffer-1  

          IF @OldestOffer = @CurrentOffer
          begin
             -- my logic
          end
     end
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```