# Query not working fine in while loop

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have  a  While  loop  where  I am trying to insert.

```
              DECLARE @CurrentOffer int  =121
        DECLARE @OldestOffer int  = 115
        DECLARE @MinClubcardID bigint=0
              DECLARE @MaxClubcardID bigint=1000
                    WHILE 1 = 1
                        BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO Temp WITH (TABLOCK)
                        SELECT  top (100) clubcard  from TempClub   with (nolock) where ID between 
                        @MinClubcardand and @MaxClubcard

                        declare @sql varchar (8000)
                        while @OldestOffer <= @CurrentOffer
                        begin
                        print @CurrentOffer
                        print @OldestOffer

                                set @sql = 'delete from Temp where Clubcard 
                                 in (select Clubcard from ClubTransaction_'+convert(varchar,@CurrentOffer)+' with (nolock))'
                                 print (@sql)
                                 exec (@sql)

                                SET @CurrentOffer = @CurrentOffer-1  
                                IF @OldestOffer = @CurrentOffer
                                    begin

                                        -- my logic
                                    end

                        end
                    end
```

My TempClub table always  checks only with first 100 records. My  TempClub table has  3000 records.
I need  to  check  all  my clubcard all  3000  records  with ClubTransaction_121,ClubTransaction_120,ClubTransaction_119 table.

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT` query in line 8 returns only the top 100 items

```
SELECT top (100) clubcard from TempClub ...
```

If you want to retrieve all items, remove the `top (100)` part of your statement

```
SELECT clubcard from TempClub ...
```

Comment: My eyes stumbled over that too. There you are looking for something complicated and ...

Comment: i am doing batch wise inserting data, so i want to extract  top 100 , and then  repeat the process until i finish all the records

Comment: Ahhh, comprehension failure on our part. Just thought you anglais was a bit stilted. Is the answer from @Chris acceptable, or didn't he get it either?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do batch type processing, you need to set the @MinClubcardID to the last ID processed plus 1 and include an ORDER BY ID to ensure that the records are being returned in order.

But... I wouldn't use the approach of using the primary key as my "index".  What you're looking for is a basic pagination pattern.  In SQL Server 2005+, Microsoft introduced the row_number() function which makes pagination a lot easier.

For example:

```
 DECLARE @T TABLE (clubcard INT)

 DECLARE @start INT
 SET @start = 0

 WHILE(1=1)
 BEGIN
   INSERT @T (clubcard)
   SELECT TOP 100 clubcard FROM 
   (
      SELECT clubcard,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS num
      FROM dbo.TempClub
   ) AS t
   WHERE num > @start

  IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0) BREAK;

  -- update counter
  SET @start = @start + 100

  -- process records found

  -- make sure temp table is empty
  DELETE FROM @T
END
```